# vb script reg exp to extract similar blocks of text

Tags: regex, vbscript

I want to extract some values from a text file. The text structure is like so, which is sort of similar to xml/html :

```
METADATA Begin

FIELD1 Begin

~~

Alias   = ~~~

~~

FIELD1 End

FIELD2 Begin

~~~

FIELD2 End

FIELD3 Begin
    FIELD4 Begin

location =  1 Terrace Way

    FIELD4 End
FIELD3 End
METADATA End
```

I have done this with linear programming but now I want to try with VB Script regular expressions.

Ideally, I want to get each block of *FIELD begin ... FIELD End* as matches so I can store them as separate strings to interrogate for internal values later. The FIELD name is variable so I cannot use that in the search, but luckily getting from *Begin ... End* will do just as good a job since I can read the FIELD form that last *FIELD End* line.

I have tried

> re.pattern = begin[\s\S]*end

but this just reads the whole file as one match. I am after the nested blocks as separate matches.

```
matches(0).Value = "METADATA Begin .... METADATA End"
matches(1).Value = "FIELD1 Begin .... FIELD1 End"
matches(2).Value = "FIELD2 Begin .... FIELD2 End"
matches(3).Value = "FIELD3 Begin .... FIELD3 End"
matches(4).Value = "FIELD4 Begin .... FIELD4 End"
```

Before I go back to reading line by line to do the job, is my idea possible using the VBS regular expressions?

Or could the VBS XML reader help (I have never used it)? After any ideas that could help.

Comment: Note the "begin" and "end" tags appear to be nested.  You should show us the exact output you want here.

Comment: Done Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: If the word "begin" can exist as text inside the block, this will make things more difficult.

Comment: Thanks @Jon P, Even without nesting, my experiments found the entire file is read instead of split into sections. Unfortunately I only know [\s\S]* to read across lines and this must be why it reads everything. I think VB Reg Exp simply is not up to such a complex job.

Comment: It seems everything is within the `METADATA Begin-End` block (except "metadata" itself). I mean you only have 1 level of nesting. Am I right?

Comment: @Mostafa F.Rad Yes, generally but there can be occasional sub nests such as the FIELD3 containing FIELD4.

Comment: I'm more concerned by something like `location = Begin Again Way` . It makes using "Begin" as any kind of delimiter ...errr... intricate

Comment: About reading across lines, regular expression engines usually provide options allowing you to define case-sensitivity or single line/multi-line process.

Comment: @Jon P
- experimenting with VB Script multiline as true or false does not appear to make a difference
- [/S/s]* seems to be the most reliable multiline search trick but is not stopping at any occurrence of END

Maybe because [\s\S] it reads any white space or non white space it carries on until the end of file. Multi line is tricky with VBS.

I think I will have to use linear techniques to isolate the nested text and then use Reg Exp to interrogate them separately.

Thank you both for the thoughts.

Comment: @Mostafa F.Rad see above. Thank you too.